# Text not changing depending on the conditions given

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

In my program, I have a switch, a text view and an accessibility service running.

When the switch is turned ON, the second screen opens from where I need to switch on my service and by doing this, the text in the first screen should change to ON(the text should change to ON only if the service is enabled).

But the problem is that the text in the first screen is changing to ON, as soon as I switch ON the switch, but before I enable my service from the second screen.

This is my code for the switch:

```
 private void setSwitchAndText(){
        boolean ifON;
        ifON = isAccessibilitySettingsOn(getApplicationContext());
        if(ifON) {
            mySwitch.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            mySwitch.setChecked(false);

        }
        myTextview.setText(ifON ? R.string.on : R.string.off);
    }
```

and this is how I check whether the service is enable or not:

```
private boolean isAccessibilitySettingsOn(Context mContext) {
        int accessibilityEnabled = 0;
        final String service = getPackageName() + "/" + myService.class.getCanonicalName();
        boolean accessibilityFound = false;

        try {
            accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "ACCESSIBILITY: " + accessibilityEnabled);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter mStringColonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');

        if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILITY IS ENABLED*** -----------------");
            String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString(
                    mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
            if (settingValue != null) {
                mStringColonSplitter.setString(settingValue);
                while (mStringColonSplitter.hasNext()) {
                    String accessibilityService = mStringColonSplitter.next();

                    Log.d(TAG, "-------------- > accessibilityService :: " + accessibilityService + " " + service);
                    if (accessibilityService.equalsIgnoreCase(service)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "We've found the correct setting - accessibility is switched on!");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILITY IS DISABLED***");
        }

        return accessibilityFound;
    }
```

and this is the relevant code in the onCreate:

```
myTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
    mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.my_switch);
    mySwitch.setChecked(false);
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            myTextview.setText(isChecked ? R.string.on : R.string.off);
            if (isChecked) {
                askToStartAccessibilityService(getResources().getString(R.string.on));
            } else {
                askToStartAccessibilityService(getResources().getString(R.string.off));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: where is isOn boleen and what is the use of ifOn boleen?

Comment: to check if the accessibility service is On or not. I am storing in that

Comment: i did not see the usage of that

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your detecting active accessibility services is pretty intense and there's no reason for this.  Try this code instead:

```
AccessibilityManager accessibilityManager = (AccessibilityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);

List<AccessibilityServiceInfo> serviceInfoList = accessibilityManager.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN);

return (serviceInfoList.size() > 0);
```

Comment: Exchange interable for list.